# How to click on element with text as "GET ROUTES" within the url https://maps.mapmyindia.com/direction using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver, display

How to click on "get routes" on "https://maps.mapmyindia.com/direction" by selenium using Python? Thanks for your help!

What I tried?
I followed this "[python selenium click on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350605/python-selenium-click-on-button#)", but this does not click.

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\pyCode\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://maps.mapmyindia.com/direction")
startLocation = driver.find_element_by_id("auto_start")
startLocation.send_keys("28.4592,77.0727")
endLocation = driver.find_element_by_id("auto_end")
endLocation.send_keys("28.4590,77.0725")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.col-xs-6.pull-right.text-right').click()
```

Comment: use `h2.get-btn` instead of `div.col-xs-6.pull-right.text-right`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed the page and it seems the "get routes" button has an id associated to it. You can simply use that

So the last line in your code should be:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("get_d").click()
```

You can use other selectors as well:

```
xpath: //a[text()='Get routes']
css: #get_d
```

When writing your test scripts, you can always validate selectors in the browser before including them in your test script. Below are a few simple approaches I follow to validate selectors:

1. When using 'id', simply use the following javascript in your browser console: `document.getElementById("get_d")`. This should return an element in the browser console if the id you are using is valid.
2. When using 'xpath', use the following line: `$x("//a[text()='Get routes']")` in the browser console. This will also return all elements associated with the xpath you mention
3. When using 'css selector', use the following line: `$$("#get_d")`. Similar to xpath approach, this will return all elements associated with the css selector you mention

Comment: Thanks @BountyHunter! It worked. I have one more question. Can you pls tell me how to get the source code of this open page?

Comment: simply use `driver.page_source`

Comment: was following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668998/selenium-how-to-get-page-source-code-after-clicking-a-button. but did not work. getting an error: "ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **GET ROUTES** on `https://maps.mapmyindia.com/direction` you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element container to be present* within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
- Then you need to remove the *attribute* **`style="display: none;"`**
- Finally, you can send the character sequence and invoke `click()` method on the element with text as **GET ROUTES**.
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://maps.mapmyindia.com/direction")
  search_tab = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.tab-pane.fade.in.search-tab.active")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", search_tab)
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control.as-input#auto").send_keys("28.4592,77.0727")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control.as-input#auto_end").send_keys("28.4590,77.0725")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h2.get-btn>a.get-route#get_d").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: map_my_india]