# Get information for products after clicking load more

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written the following code to get me information from a webpage that displays some products, and then on clciking 'load more', more products are displayed. On running the code below, I only get information for the first few products. I think the code is correct, there is a small error somewhere that I am not able to catch. Would be great if someone could help me resolve this. Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xlsxwriter

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://justnebulizers.com/collections/nebulizer-accessories")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
time.sleep(4)

button= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']")
button.click() 
time.sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

def cpap_spider(url):
    source_code= requests.get(url)
    plain_text= source_code.text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class":"product-info__caption"}):
            
        href="https://www.justnebulizers.com"+link.get("href")
        #title= link.string
        each_item(href)    
        print(href)
            #print(title)

def each_item(item_url):
    global cols_names, row_i
    source_code= requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text= source_code.text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    table=soup.find("table", {"class":"tab_table"})
    if table:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    else:
        row_i+=1
        return
    for row in table_rows:
      cols = row.find_all('td')
      for ele in range(0,len(cols)):
        temp = cols[ele].text.strip()
        if temp:
          # Here if you want then you can remove unwanted characters like : ? from temp
          # For example "Actual Weight" and ""
          if temp[-1:] == ":":
            temp = temp[:-1]
          # Name of column
          if ele == 0:
            try:
              cols_names_i = cols_names.index(temp)
            except:
              cols_names.append(temp)
              cols_names_i = len(cols_names) -  1
              worksheet.write(0, cols_names_i + 1, temp)
              continue;
          worksheet.write(row_i, cols_names_i + 1, temp)      
    row_i += 1
    
cols_names=[]
cols_names_i = 0
row_i = 1
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('respiratory_care.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, "href")
    
cpap_spider("https://justnebulizers.com/collections/nebulizer-accessories")
#each_item("https://www.1800cpap.com/viva-nasal-cpap-mask-by-3b-medical")       
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting.

Comment: I get no error, i don't get the desired output. Which is to have information for all products including those generated after clicking 'load more'. I only get information for the products that are immediately visible in the display

Comment: Using BeautifulSoup will not return anything that happens after you interact with the page like clicking a button.

Comment: How do i proceed then?

Comment: You will have to stick with selenium.

Comment: @Jortega: are you sure? surely Beautifulsoup can navigate any html code you give it. So if the html code is changed after you click the button you could feed that html code into BS4. @huy: have you checked whether or not your `driver.page_source` actually changes after you've clicked the button?

Comment: @Beek I thought so too. I just checked.It does not! However I dont understand where im going wrong

Comment: @huy maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668998/selenium-how-to-get-page-source-code-after-clicking-a-button) helps? your problem could be that the page hasn't fully loaded after a 1 second wait?

Comment: @Beek yes Beautifulsoup can navigate any html code you give it but some of these javascript frameworks like Angular or React load the DOM in such a way that `driver.page_source` does not return everything you think it should.

Comment: @Jortega I'm not sure any frameworks other that plain javacript and jquery are being used. But I'm also not sure that means that "BeautifulSoup will not return anything that happens after you interact with the page...". I do know that the website takes a few seconds to load the extra items (on my computer/network anyway). So waiting a little longer or explicitly might just do it for OP.

Comment: you realise that your `cpap_spider` function doesn't actually use the changed page? You make a new `soup` variable in it and give it the html from the original page. So when you find the way to change your `soup` variable after clicking, you still need to add that to your `cpap_spider` function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click that button and scroll down. So I used:

```
while True:
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']").click()
                print('button found')
                time.sleep(2)
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                print('scrolled down')
                
            except:
                print('button not found')
                break
```

And I fixed some issues in your code.

This code will load all of the products:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xlsxwriter

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

def cpap_spider(url):
    driver.get(url)
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']").click()
            print('button found')
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            print('scrolled down')
            
        except:
            print('button not found')
            break
    ''' As a list
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-info__caption")
    links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in elems]
    print(links)'''
    for link in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-info__caption"):
            
        href="https://www.justnebulizers.com"+link.get_attribute("href")
        #title= link.string
        #each_item(href)    
        print(href)
            #print(title)
        
def each_item(item_url):
    global cols_names, row_i
    source_code= requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text= source_code.text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    table=soup.find("table", {"class":"tab_table"})
    if table:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    else:
        row_i+=1
        return
    for row in table_rows:
      cols = row.find_all('td')
      for ele in range(0,len(cols)):
        temp = cols[ele].text.strip()
        if temp:
          # Here if you want then you can remove unwanted characters like : ? from temp
          # For example "Actual Weight" and ""
          if temp[-1:] == ":":
            temp = temp[:-1]
          # Name of column
          if ele == 0:
            try:
              cols_names_i = cols_names.index(temp)
            except:
              cols_names.append(temp)
              cols_names_i = len(cols_names) -  1
              worksheet.write(0, cols_names_i + 1, temp)
              continue;
          worksheet.write(row_i, cols_names_i + 1, temp)      
    row_i += 1
    
cols_names=[]
cols_names_i = 0
row_i = 1
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('respiratory_care.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, "href")
    
cpap_spider("https://justnebulizers.com/collections/nebulizer-accessories")
#each_item("https://www.1800cpap.com/viva-nasal-cpap-mask-by-3b-medical")       
workbook.close()
```

Comment: this does not work. it loads no entries to the excel file, and also displaysthe links of the first set of products only in the output

Comment: `cpap_spider(url)` function is working fine. It gets all of the products.