# Error while adding explicit wait condition selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a page that lists some products, and on clicking 'load more', more products are listed. I want to retrieve information from these product pages. I wrotw the code using selenium to click the button in an automated manner. But it seems the rest of the code does not wait until the button is clicked. So i added an explicit wait condition but it shows an error that it should have 3 arguments instead of 2. What could be going wrong here?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import xlsxwriter

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://justnebulizers.com/collections/nebulizer-accessories")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
#time.sleep(2)
wait= WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']"))
button= driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']"))
button.click() 
#time.sleep(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

def cpap_spider(url):
    source_code= requests.get(url)
    plain_text= source_code.text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.findAll("a", {"class":"product-info__caption"}):
            
        href="https://www.justnebulizers.com"+link.get("href")
        #title= link.string
        each_item(href)    
        print(href)
            #print(title)

def each_item(item_url):
    global cols_names, row_i
    source_code= requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text= source_code.text
    soup= BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    table=soup.find("table", {"class":"tab_table"})
    if table:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    else:
        row_i+=1
        return
    for row in table_rows:
      cols = row.find_all('td')
      for ele in range(0,len(cols)):
        temp = cols[ele].text.strip()
        if temp:
          # Here if you want then you can remove unwanted characters like : ? from temp
          # For example "Actual Weight" and ""
          if temp[-1:] == ":":
            temp = temp[:-1]
          # Name of column
          if ele == 0:
            try:
              cols_names_i = cols_names.index(temp)
            except:
              cols_names.append(temp)
              cols_names_i = len(cols_names) -  1
              worksheet.write(0, cols_names_i + 1, temp)
              continue;
          worksheet.write(row_i, cols_names_i + 1, temp)      
    row_i += 1
    
cols_names=[]
cols_names_i = 0
row_i = 1
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('respiratory_care.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write(0, 0, "href")
    
cpap_spider("https://justnebulizers.com/collections/nebulizer-accessories")
#each_item("https://www.1800cpap.com/viva-nasal-cpap-mask-by-3b-medical")       
workbook.close()
```

I get this error-**init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Can you mark the line where the error occurred..

Comment: wait.until(ec.invisibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH,"//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']"))

Comment: Why are you calling wait before pressing the button?

Comment: if i make it invisible before clicking, how will the execution happen?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `()`

```
wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']")))
```

Comment: <ipython-input-30-03c5b528ff3b> in <module>
     ---> 16 wait.until(ec.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='load-more__btn action_button continue-button']")))
     
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

Comment: That line is working, it just did not find the element you are looking for. Can you post the relevant HTML, I can adjust the xpath.

Comment: Sure, here it is - https://justnebulizers.com/collections/respiratory-care

Comment: The issue was `invisibility_of_element_located` I would suggest `element_to_be_clickable`. See the updated answer.

Comment: But i want the code to proceed only after the button is clicked...this does not ensure that?

Comment: Could you check this please?- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695039/get-information-for-products-after-clicking-load-more